# Hopf-Rinow theorem (Metric completeness implies Geodesic completeness)

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I use Petersen's book.

> [image]

1. How do we know $\hat{K}$ takes exactly the form in the description? Specifically the condition $|v| \leq |\hat{\dot{c}} |$
2. Pretty sure there is a minor typo. They want to relabel first $\mu:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ with $\mu(0) = q$ and $\dot{\mu}(0) = v$. Now how does $\mu$ patch with the $c(t_j) \in K$? If $b$ is arbitrary large and $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary small, there should be a gap right?

> [image]

3. So the contradiction is that $[0,b)$ is maximal? Can someone spill out the details for me?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do we know $\hat{K}$ takes exactly the form in the description? Specifically the condition $|v| \leq |\hat{\dot{c}} |$

The choice $\lvert v\rvert\leq \lvert\dot c\rvert$ is pretty arbitrary, we only need it to contain what we need for the argument that follows, but I suppose a $\leq$ looks more intuitive (e.g., corresponds to closed ball being the first example of compact sets).

> 2. Pretty sure there is a minor typo. They want to relabel first $\mu:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ with $\mu(0) = q$ and $\dot{\mu}(0) = v$.

No, I don't see any typo here.  It is an abuse of the letter $c$ for curve. :-)  Let's change to $\mu$ as you suggested.

> (cont'd) Now how does $\mu$ patch with the $c(t_j) \in K$?

You have $\hat K$ and now choose $\varepsilon$ so that for every tangent vector in $\hat K$ the exponential map is defined for time up to $\pm\varepsilon$ (noninclusive). Now we have earlier chosen a sequence $t_j\uparrow b<\infty$.  At $t_j$, the geodesic was still defined, so we have $(c(t_j),\dot c(t_j))$, and this pair is in $\hat K$.
So for some $0<\delta\leq\varepsilon$, we have two curves:
$c(t_j+\tau)$ and $\mu_{c(t_j),\dot c(t_j)}(\tau)$, both defined for $\lvert\tau\rvert<\delta$ and has the same initial data at $\tau=0$.  So they have to agree.  Hence we may patch them together and extend the curve $c$ to at least time $\max(b,t_j+\varepsilon)>b$ (possibly excluding the end-point), contradicting the choice of $b$.

So we have proved:

> **Result**: A geodesic $c$ that cannot be extended indefinitely to time $+\infty$ must leave every compact set, i.e., for each compact $K\subseteq M$ there is a time $t_K<\sup\operatorname{dom}c$ such that $c(t)\notin K$ for all $t>t_K$, $t\in\operatorname{dom} c$.

which will be used later.

> (cont'd) If $b$ is arbitrary large and $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary small, there should be a gap right?

No, the order of choice is

- $b$ was chosen first (as the time the geodesic "falls off the manifold")
- A sequence $t_j\uparrow b$ chosen by "not leaving a compact $K\subseteq M$"
- compact $\hat{K}\subset TM$ chosen to contain $\dot{c}(t_j)$
- $\varepsilon>0$ chosen a bit later, depending on $K$,
- A specific $t_j\in (t_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ chosen within $\varepsilon$ of $b$

so you can't move $b$ somewhere else now.

> 3. So the contradiction is that $[0,b)$ is maximal? Can someone spill out the details for me?

Suppose $M$ is complete under metric $d$, and that, contrary to (1), there is a geodesic cannot be extended beyond $(-a,b)$, $b<\infty$, $0<a\leq\infty$.  Then we have two conflicting conditions

- $c$ is a geodesic, so $d(c(s),c(t))\leq\lvert s-t\rvert\cdot\lvert\dot c\rvert$ for all $s,t\in[0,b)$.  So there is a Cauchy sequence, say $x_n=c(b-2^{-n})$, which must therefore converges to some $x\in M$ since $M$ is metrically complete.  So $K=\{c(t):t\in[0,b)\}\cup\{x\}$ is compact.
- But $c$ leaves every compact set before time $b$, so it must leave the compact set $K$, i.e., there exists a time $t_K$ such that $c(t)\notin K$ for $t_K<t<b$, which it can't do.  conttradiction!

Comment: 1. So it could have maybe been in the form $|v| \geq |c'|$?

2. So at $\tau = 0$, $c(t_j) = \mu(0) = q$ using that $t_j \in (\tau-\delta, \tau+\delta)$ and applying the existence theorem?

3. (cont'd) Well that's what i mean, if $b = 1000$ and $\epsilon = 0.1$, there is no way to patch this.

4. So the first part says it stays in $K$, but previous discussion say it leave $K$ and therefore $b$ cannot exist and $b$ must extend for all time?

Comment: 1. No, it needs to be compact (so we can find an $\varepsilon>0$ uniformly for $K$), so $\lvert v\rvert$ for $v\in K$ has to be bounded and contains the $\dot c$.  2-4. Yes.

Comment: No, no, no. I mean that it is even possible to patch the two geodesics if we choose  $b$ to be large from the start.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  $b$ is not really a choice, it is forced by the geodesic and its starting point.

Comment: We are given that $\mu: (a,b)\to M$ is a geodesic with $b < \infty$ $b$ is arbitrary here, so that's what I mean when we have a choice on it.

Comment: No, we have the condition $c\colon(a,b)\to M$ is maximal, which fixes $b$ for a given starting data.

Comment: I am not understanding this, what's stopping the initial data to fix $b$ to be large?  Why the initial data will force $b$ to be small enough ($\epsilon$ small) so we can do the patching?

Comment: You are confusing the geodesic $c$ (defined on $(a,b)$, start at $(c(0),\dot c(0))$, $b$ could be very large) with the $\mu$ (defined at least on $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$) that starts at $(c(t_j),\dot c(t_j))$.  In the proof we patch $c$ and $\mu$ by $$\tilde{c}(t)=\begin{cases}c(t) & t\leq t_j\\\mu(t-t_j)& t\geq t_j\end{cases}$$ noting $t_j<b<t_j+\varepsilon$.  Note the time $t_j$ here is very close to $b$.

Comment: So I think I have an idea of what is going on. When they defined $\hat{K}$ and $\mu_{q,v}$, they actually want to define $\mu(0) = c(t_j)$ not $\mu(0) = q$ (unless I am wrong here). Also my original confusion was that the interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ must be in overlap with $(a,b)$ which led to the whole "gap" I was speaking of. Also it occurred to me that $a > 0$ because I guess "negative time" in the geodesic doesn't make a lot of sense?